# "Http channel implementation doesn't support nsIUploadChannel2. An extension has supplied a non-functional http protocol handler"

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I'm writing a Firefox extension that uses lots of XMLHttpRequests, following the pattern of [the sample code at MDC](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest). Most of the time this works perfectly, but some of the requests are causing the following message to appear in the console:

> > > Http channel implementation doesn't support nsIUploadChannel2. An extension has supplied a non-functionalhttp protocol handler. This will break behavior and in future releases not work at all.

As far as I can tell, my extension is not supplying any new http protocol handler; it's just using what is built into Firefox. It's not another extension, because I tried disabling all other extensions, and got the same result. I also don't see any particular pattern for why I get this message for some requests but not others.

What does this message mean, and what, if anything, am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** This often seems to happen when I'm sending two XmlHttpRequests, one right after the other. I bring this up because I just happened to come across [this page about how the browser will only send two requests at once, and will queue up any others internally](http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2006/10/what_i_didnt_know_about_xhr.html). So it might be related to that, but I don't know.

Comment: What URI schemes are you seeing this with?

Comment: I asked about this on the Mozilla IRC channel, and they recommended I file a bug. So I did: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596292

Comment: After digging a little further, it turned out this was happening because I was trying to get the source of a page using an XMLHttpRequest to a `view-source:` URL. As someone on Bugzilla kindly pointed out, this is kind of pointless. I'm now using this technique http://mozilla-xp.com/mozilla.dev.extensions/How-to-load-a-cached-page-into-an-invisible-browser-using-javascript-kind which is actually doing what I intended -- getting the source from the cache without making a new HTTP request. Long story short: Nevermind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting as an anwer:

it turned out this was happening because I was trying to get the source of a page using an XMLHttpRequest to a view-source: URL ([bugzilla bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=596292)).

As someone on Bugzilla kindly pointed out, this is kind of pointless. I'm now using [this technique](http://mozilla-xp.com/mozilla.dev.extensions/How-to-load-a-cached-page-into-an-invisible-browser-using-javascript-kind) which is actually doing what I intended -- getting the source from the cache without making a new HTTP request.